# Javascript AA Font enlargment accessibility

Tags: javascript, accessibility

OK basically i need help to create a code that increase font size on a mouse click. 
Here is an example:
http://www.rnib.org.uk/ in the top right corner there are 3 AAA's which increase the pages font size etc

my current code is

```
// JavaScript Document
var min = 12;
var max = 32;

function increaseFontSize() {
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (p[i].style.fontSize) {
            var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px", ""));
        } else {

            var s = 12;
        }
        if (s != max) {
            s += 1;
        }
        p[i].style.fontSize = s + "px"
    }
}

function decreaseFontSize() {
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

        if (p[i].style.fontSize) {
            var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px", ""));
        } else {
            var s = 12;
        }
        if (s != min) {
            s -= 1;
        }
        p[i].style.fontSize = s + "px"
    }
}
```

it is implemented in the HTML like this:

```
<a href="javascript:decreaseFontSize();">-</a>
<a href="javascript:increaseFontSize();">+</a>
```

mine only works for items tagged as 'p' can anyone help me create it so the function works like the RNIB.org website cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be overcomplicating things.  I would approach this issue more from a CSS perspective with a little minor work through JS. I would:

- Use a class name on a container element
- Use CSS to style several different sizes
- Use JS to change the class name when the plus/minus links are clicked

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:smallFontSize();">Small Font</a>
<a href="javascript:largeFontSize();">Large Font</a>
<a href="javascript:normalFontSize();">Normal Font</a>

<div id="myContainer" class="size-normal">
  <h1>Some header</h1>
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Some list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myContainer.size-normal { font-size: 12px; }
#myContainer.size-large { font-size: 14px; }
#myContainer.size-small { font-size: 10px; }
```

JS:

```
var containerEle = document.getElementById('myContainer');
function smallFontSize() {
  containerEle.className = "size-small";
}
function largeFontSize() {
  containerEle.className = "size-large";
}
function normalFontSize() {
  containerEle.className = "size-normal";
}
```

Comment: Yes i'm about to test this now but it looks, like this could be the way i wanted it Cheers.

Comment: my Debugger is responding that 'containerEle.className = "size-small";'

containerEle = null???

Comment: did you add the "myContainer" id to a wrapper element (like in my example above)?

Comment: Do you have the line: `var containerEle = document.getElementById('myContainer');`

Comment: Also, where are you including the JS? I hope after you add the `myContainer` element to the page.

Comment: The CSS is the right approach! However, the JS would be better off either in an onclick handler instead of on the href.  (Better still would be to add the +/- buttons through JS, so non JS users never see non-functioning buttons.)

Comment: Jeremy - I completely agree with both statements (onlick handler and progressive enhancement). However, I didn't want to move too far away from the OP's original approach (and possibly understanding) of the JS.

Comment: even better would be to have the default href in the anchors actually link to a new document with increased/decreased font size, thereby providing a fallback for users without js.

Answer (score 2):

If your CSS is set up so that you have a body font-size set to 100% and all element font sizes defined as 1.1 em, 1.5em, etc. Then your buttons can trigger these to increase or decrease the font size of the whole page.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize.smaller;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize.larger;
```

All elements will then change size relative to each other, e.g. your h1, h2, etc. will still be bigger than your p elements.

I would consider 'larger' and 'smaller' buttons more user-friendly than three predefined sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this just for your site, what if you keep the icons there, but when someone presses them, you show a popup explaining that [zoom/font-size increase is built-in to almost every browser](http://www.health.ny.gov/help/text_size.htm) out there already?

That gets around the complications of writing a script or what interval to use for the font size, plus it has the added benefit of teaching users that this functionality is already available on almost any website they use.

You can also do a little UA sniffing to determine which hot-key they should press and show that in the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not recommended to increase/decrease the font size by 1 every click. It is because you have to iterate many elements and set the font size. I will suggestion use 3-5 class to define the font-size and set to body to affect the further elements. But if you insist to increase/decrease the font size by 1 every click, you can reference the following code. If you would like to select elements from header, you can select it like this `document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("h1")`

```
function increaseFontSizeInternal(list) {
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {   
        var s = 12;
        if(list[i].style.fontSize) 
        { 
            s = parseInt(list[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
        }
        if(s!=max)
        {
            s += 1; 
        } 
        list[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"
    }
} 

function increaseFontSize()
{
    var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    increaseFontSizeInternal(paragraph);
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    increaseFontSizeInternal(links);
    var headerInMenu = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("h1")
    increaseFontSizeInternal(headerInMenu);
}

function decreaseFontSizeInternal(list) 
{ 
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++) 
    {   
        var s = 12;
        if(list[i].style.fontSize) 
        {
            s = parseInt(list[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
        } 
        if(s!=min) {
            s -= 1;
        }
        list[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"
    }
} 

function decreaseFontSize()
{
    var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    decreaseFontSizeInternal(paragraph);
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    decreaseFontSizeInternal(links);
    var headerInMenu = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("h1")
    decreaseFontSizeInternal(headerInMenu);
}
```

Comment: Currently the script works but will only increase anything tagged a <p> , i was asking how do i make it effect other element such as my navigation bars and headers??

Comment: which one should i call in my html Increase font size or increase font size internal?

Comment: saying that 'list' is undefined

Comment: the one without internal .decreaseFontSize and increaseFontSize

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to just to change page zoom. This will not break the design of website.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:$('body').css({'zoom':parseFloat($('body').css('zoom'))+0.1})">A+</a><br>
<a href="javascript:$('body').css({'zoom':parseFloat($('body').css('zoom'))-0.1})">A-</a>
```